# Depending on version X.Y.* of a package

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm trying to tighten up the dependencies of a Debian package of mine. This package is rather tightly coupled with the `ghc` package, needing a `ghc` with a particular major and minor version number to work, but doesn't care about any "lesser" versions.

Essentially, I want to be able to depend on `ghc (= 7.8.*)`, but that doesn't seem possible. I've also looked around for a way to specify `ghc (>= 7.8, << 7.9)` as a workaround and found that it's possible to specify `ghc (>= 7.8), ghc (<< 7.9)`, but this looked very hackish to me.

Is there a nicer way to express this?

Answer (score 0):

> I […] found that it's possible to specify `ghc (>= 7.8), ghc (<< 7.9)`, […]
>
> Is there a nicer way to express this?

No.